# Are "tabs" always represented by 4 no break spaces?

Tags: html, localization, utf

When you produce or require a "tab delimited" document, are those tabs always represented by 4 `&nbsp;`?  What happens in other part of the worlds, and what happens when the encoding of the document changes (e.g., text copy-pasted in an HTML form versus UTF-8 .txt files uploaded)?

Here I am not talking about documents generated by programmers.  I am talking of documents generated by random users to be used in a web app.  One example could be a list of ingredients (tab separated) for a cooking site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab delimited documents should be delimited by the tab character, not by spaces.  It's not done for layout, it's all about separating content by a delimiter, in this case the tab.  It's just like a comma delimited file - the commas separate the data, but have no meaning other than as separators.

Answer (score 0):

Each software/platform can decide how they interpret the "tab",  sometime it's 4 spaces, sometimes it's 2...

So to answer your question directly: No, you can't assume that "Tabs" always represent by 4 no break space.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are different characters, not spaces.  The HTML entity is `&#09;`.